# How to correctly format this code?

Tags: java, string

The intent of this code is to get it to check if a `String` has a vowel; if so, it doubles it. I cannot use `StringReplace`, `StringBuilder`, or .append on this assignment. I'm receiving an error when I run this code. Could someone point out the error in my syntax.

```
public String doubleVowels(String str) 
{
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char ca = str.charAt(i);
        if (ca == "a" || ca == "e" || ca =="i" || ca == "o" || ca == "u")
        {
            ca = str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
            ca = Character.toString(ca);
        }
        return str;
     }
}
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: What do you expect get when you add two characters together?

Comment: Include a test case like sample input and sample output.

Comment: I'm using a limited compiler made for this assignment so I'm not sure if its any use, but the error is "root/Grader.java:9: error: incomparable types: char and String
        if (ca == "a" || ca == "e" || ca =="i" || ca == "o" || ca == "u")
               ^
root/Grader.java:9: error: incomparable types: char and String
        if (ca == "a" || ca == "e" || ca =="i" || ca == "o" || ca == "u")
                            ^                                                                                          ...." It goes on and on.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `char.equals`. `char` is a primitive type and does not have a `.equals` method. Use `==` to compare characters:

`if (ca == 'a')`, etc.

Comment: yikes, forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: @HarryYou Happy to help. Please upvote and accept if this was useful.

Comment: I did; I'm just too low of a rep to make it visible

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here...

**The `char` type**

`ca` is a `char`, which means it holds a single character.  You can't make it equal to two characters

```
//a char plus a char is a char, not two chars (which is a String)
ca = str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
```

You can't store a `String` in a `char`

```
//You are creating a String and trying to store it in ca, a char
ca = Character.toString(ca);
```

**Method arguments and return values**

You are returning the `str` passed to your method without having modified it and you are doing it after the first character has been tested (because it's inside the loop that steps through `str`:-

```
//The String returned will always be the same as the one passed in
return str;
```

**Java quotes**

Lastly, you are using double quotes (`"`), which means `String` and trying to compare it to a `char`.  You need to use single quotes (`'`) so you are comparing `char` with `char`:-

```
//This is the source of "error: incomparable types"
if (ca == "a" || ca == "e" || ca =="i" || ca == "o" || ca == "u")
```

---

**Solution**

You want to return a new string that is the `ca` or is the `ca` twice if it's a vowel:-

```
String newString = "" + ca; //ca added once
if (ca == 'a' || ca == 'e' || ca =='i' || ca == 'o' || ca == 'u')
   newString += ca; //ca added again if it's a vowel
```

You'll also want to append this new `String` to a complete `String` ever loop cycle then return it after all the loops:-

```
String changedString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
  //the above code
  changedString += newString;
}
return changedString;
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but would something like "String vowel = ca + ca;" work after ca has been converted to a string?

Comment: yes, it would autobox `ca` to `String` in this case.  But you may need to do `String vowel = "" + ca + ca`

Comment: @RossDrew - That is not autoboxing.  Autoboxing only applies to the conversion of a primitive type to its wrapper type.  Autoboxing a `char` gives a `Character` not a `String`.  If `ca` is a `String` (like Harry proposes) then `ca + ca` is a string concatenation ...

Comment: My bad, auto-convert. NOT autobox

Answer (score 0):

the type of `ca` is `char`,  `ca = str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);` dont make sense.

Comment: May I ask if there is a way to change the value of ca. I'm currently lost in my choice of syntax as I'm not really knowledgeable in this area. I recently started into Strings and Chars intensely about three days ago...

Answer (score -1):

Your code have few bugs following code will work

```
public static String doubleVowels(String str) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char ca = str.charAt(i);
        if (ca == 'a' || ca == 'e' || ca =='i' || ca == 'o' || ca == 'u' ||
        ca == 'A' || ca == 'E' || ca =='I' || ca == 'O' || ca == 'U')
        {
            str = (str.substring(0,i)+ca+ca+str.substring(i+1));
            i++;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Problems with your code:

- You return code inside for loop.
- You are completely lost at making the Vowel double.I am taking the substring until the character you are at than add the double character and than append the remaining substring.
- I increase the index after that since I have modified the string and next character is same character.
- Once done iterating through all the characters than I return the string.

I hope this is an acceptable answer.

`Input: "Hello world"`

`Output: "Heelloo Woorld"`

Comment: Bless you dude, totally didn't think about substrings. +1'd

Comment: Happy to help @HarryYou. Please give an upvote rather than typing +1'd